# regex for double and single quotes in PHP

Tags: php, regex, quotes

I'm trying to make a regex that will match the argument for a function in PHP. The only problem is the regex doesn't work, or I'm not escaping it well, since I need both double quotes and single quotes to be matched, depending on what the developer used in code.

```
fn_name("string");
fn_name('string');
```

I've made two expressions, one for each case, but I guess that can be done way better.

```
/fn_name\("(.*?)\"\)/
/fn_name\('(.*?)\'\)/
```

How do I make that one regex, and escape it properly from this?

```
preg_match_all('/fn_name\("(.*?)\"\)/', file_get_contents($filename), $out);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `["']` and backreference (`\1`):

```
preg_match_all('/fn_name\((["\'])(.*?)\1\)/', "fn_name('string');", $out);
preg_match_all('/fn_name\((["\'])(.*?)\1\)/', 'fn_name("string");', $out);
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/ydWck1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$s = <<<END
fn_name("string"); fn_name("same line");
fn_name(   "str\"ing"   );
fn_name("'str'ing'");

fn_name   ('string');
fn_name('str\'ing'   );
fn_name(  '"st"ring"');

fn_name("string'); # INVALID
fn_name('string"); # INVALID
END;

preg_match_all('~fn_name\s*\(\s*([\'"])(.+?)\1\s*\)~', $s, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($match);
```

- [Regex explanation](http://regex101.com/r/eG3rW4)
- [PHP demo](https://eval.in/54184)